# On First load of jqgrid how to load page of specific record?

Tags: jqgrid

Using Jquery.Jqgrid v4.4.4
     I have 10 pages in my State grid, i want to display the page which holds state name 'Tamilnadu' on first of the jqgrid loads. Not to bring the state on the first page, need to display that page on the first time.

EDIT: My Jqgrid code, here i have 'State' column contains 10+ pages , in one of the page 'Tamilnadu' state record is there. Please help me on how to load the grid with that page on first load.

```js
// Setting up County Grid properties
$(function () {
    $("#CountyGrid").jqGrid({
        url: '/ControlTables/GetCountyResult',
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
        mtype: 'Get',
        colNames: ['CountyIdentifier', 'Active', 'State', 'County', 'County Number', AddNewBtn],
        colModel: [
        {
            Key: true, name: 'CountyIdentifier', index: 'CountyIdentifier', width: 16, editable: false, sortable: true, align: "left", classes: "grid-col",
            hidden: true, displayName: "CountyIdentifier"
        },
        {
            name: 'ActiveFlag', index: 'ActiveFlag', width: 4, align: 'center', editable: true,
            edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False", defaultValue: "True" }, formatter: "checkbox", displayName: "Active"
        },
        {
            name: 'StateIdentifier', index: 'StateIdentifier', editable: true, formatter: 'select', sortable: true,
            edittype: 'select', width: 19, align: "left", classes: "grid-col", editoptions: { style: "height:23px;" }, displayName: "State", valueField: "StateText",
        },
        {
            name: 'CountyText', index: 'CountyText', width: 19, editable: true, sortable: true, align: "left", classes: "grid-col",
            editoptions: { style: "height:23px;", maxlength: "48", dataInit: function (el) { $(el).css('text-transform', 'uppercase'); } }, displayName: "County"
        },
        {
            name: 'CountyNumber', index: 'CountyNumber', width: 7, editable: true, sortable: true, align: "left", classes: "grid-col",
            editoptions: { style: "height:23px;", maxlength: "5" }, displayName: "County Number"
        },
        {
            name: "action", index: "action", sortable: false, editable: false, align: "center", width: "7", displayName: "Action"
        },
        ],

        // Call select row function
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            if (onPagingLastSel) {
                $('#CountyGrid').jqGrid('resetSelection', lastsel, true);
                onPagingLastSel = false;
            }
            rowSelect(id);
        },

        onPaging: function () {
            //Prompt to save pending changes when the user try to navigate Next/Previous/Front/Last page.
            if (lastsel != null) {
                $('#CountyGrid').jqGrid('saveRow', lastsel, {});
                var editrowData = jQuery("#CountyGrid").getRowData(lastsel);
                var editRow_ActiveFlag = editrowData['ActiveFlag']
                var editRow_StateIdentifier = editrowData['StateIdentifier']
                var editRow_CountyText = editrowData['CountyText']
                var editRow_CountyNumber = editrowData['CountyNumber']                
                $('#CountyGrid').jqGrid('editRow', lastsel, {});
                if ((lastsel_StateIdentifier != editRow_StateIdentifier && editRow_StateIdentifier != undefined)||
                    (lastsel_CountyText != editRow_CountyText && editRow_CountyText != undefined) ||
                    (lastsel_CountyNumber != editRow_CountyNumber && editRow_CountyNumber != undefined) ||
                    (lastsel_ActiveFlag != editRow_ActiveFlag && editRow_ActiveFlag != undefined)) {
                    DialogConfirmSave("GENL-002");
                    onPagingLastSel = true;
                    return 'stop';
                }
                else {
                    lastsel = null;
                    //enable New Button
                    $("#NewBtnId").removeClass('add-new-button-disable');
                    $("#NewBtnId").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            }
        },

        // load all States into jqGrid dropdown 
        beforeProcessing: function (response) {
            var $self = $(this),
            options = response.colModelOptions, StateIdentifier;
            if (options != null) {
                for (StateIdentifier in options) {
                    if (options.hasOwnProperty(StateIdentifier)) {
                        $("#CountyGrid").jqGrid("setColProp", StateIdentifier, options[StateIdentifier]);
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        // Grid column header alignment to the left diable new button for general users
        loadComplete: function () {           
            $("#CountyGrid").jqGrid("setLabel", "Active", "", { "text-align": "left" })
            $("#CountyGrid").jqGrid("setLabel", "StateIdentifier", "", { "text-align": "left" })
            $("#CountyGrid").jqGrid("setLabel", "CountyText", "", { "text-align": "left" })
            $("#CountyGrid").jqGrid("setLabel", "CountyNumber", "", { "text-align": "left" })
        },

        pager: jQuery('#CountyPager'),
        rowNum: jqGridRowCount,
        rowList: GridRowList,
        viewrecords: true,
        emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            Id: "0"
        },
        multiselect: false,
        autowidth: true,
        height: 560,
        hidegrid: false,
    }).navGrid('#CountyPager', {
        edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false, reload: false, restoreAfterSelect: false
    })
});
```

My Controller code:

```cs
public JsonResult GetCountyResult(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, bool getAllRecords = false)
{
    objCountyViewModel = new CountyViewModel();
    int totalRecords = 0;
    if (Session["CountyList"] != null && Session["CountyList"] is List<CountyModel>)
    {
        objCountyViewModel.CountyModelList = (List<CountyModel>)Session["CountyList"];
        if (objCountyViewModel.CountyModelList != null)
        {
            Session["CountyList"] = objCountyViewModel.SortCounty(sidx, sord);
            totalRecords = objCountyViewModel.CountyModelList.Count();
        }
    }
    var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)rows);
    rows = getAllRecords ? totalRecords : rows;

    var jsonData = new
    {
        colModelOptions = new
        {
            StateIdentifier = new
            {
                formatter = "select",
                edittype = "select",
                editoptions = new
                {
                    value = objCountyViewModel.GetStateDropdownList()
                }
            }
        },
        total = totalPages,
        page,
        records = totalRecords,
        rows = objCountyViewModel.GetCountyPageList(page, rows)
    };
    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: jqGrid 4.4.4 is **very old** (almost 5 years old) and deprecated since a long time. If you use NuGet package [jQuery.jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.jqGrid/) then I'd recommended you to uninstall it and install [free-jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/) 4.15.2 instead. You use [jqgrid-asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid-asp.net/info) to your question, which reference *another* commercial product. Please, include more details which shows what you do. It's unclear which `datatype` you use, which format have input data and so on.

Comment: Free jqGrid allows to sort and filter the data even if you load the grid via `datatype: "local", loadonce: true`. You can use `forceClientSorting: true` option for that. Additionally it supports `lastSelectedData` option, which is close to `data`, but provides sorted and filtered data in the order in which the data will be displayed. One can use the information to calculate the page which you need. Alternatively you can just sort the data so that the required data will be displayed first. In any way one need more details to be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have updated my post. Please refer the Edit part.

Comment: Could you describe more detailed what you want to implement? You wrote: "i want to display the page which holds state name 'Tamilnadu' on first of the jqgrid loads". You don't use currently `sortname` (no sorting). You can  **sort** the data by state before displaying so that the state 'Tamilnadu' be the first. Moreover, it seem that you have small number of total rows. 10 pages means probably about 250 pages. Is it so? If you have less at 1000 or 10000 rows then `loadonce: true` would be the best choice. The solution will heavy depend on the **version/fork** of jqGrid, which you can use.

Comment: It would be helpful if you include an example of JSON data returned from the server (2 rows of main data would be enough). Currently you use many options and properties, which are not correct. For example, you use `Key: true` property in `CountyIdentifier` column. Is the values in the column unique? Then you should use `key: true` instead of `Key: true`. You can use `jsonReader: { id: "CountyIdentifier" }, prmNames: { "CountyIdentifier" }` and **remove** unneeded hidden column `"CountyIdentifier"`. Ex example of JSON data could understand your code better and suggest you to fix minor bugs.

Comment: I forgot to include the link to the demo, which demonstrates the speed of local paging/string/filtering. The demo https://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-5000-25-free-jqgrid.htm creates the grid with 5000 rows, 13 columns and displays the data with 25 rows per page. You can test the performance of the grid yourself. The performance of the grid with 250 rows is even more better. The round-trip to the server is typically longer as working with local grid.